# Can you free-tag multiple aspects at once?

Tags: combat, dresden-files, aspects

Assuming you are fighting an opponent one-on-one and they have used consequences to negate stress and placed aspects on themself, could you tag two of those consequences for free on one roll, if they haven't been tagged before?

I know it says something about tagging multiple aspects if you're lifting something with might and they help you somewhere else in the book. But I don't know if it applies to combat.

Comment: Are you asking if you can them tag them for the same roll which put them there, thus upping it?

Comment: No. Just multiple tags on the same roll and on a different turn.

Comment: Are you asking if you can tag them for free?

Comment: Yes. If they hadn't been tagged before. I know you can tag one of them. But I was wondering if you can tag multiple. I know it says something about tagging multiple if you're lifting something  with might and they help you somewhere else in the book. But I don't know if it applies to combat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes you can**, if you are the one who caused those consequences, or if that person allows you to.